# When is the query executed(table data blocks scanned,correct rows read) exactly when the out parameter of Oracle Procedure is sys_refcursor

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I have  a procedure like the following signature , which is being called by Java frontend:

```
PROCEDURE MY_PROCEDURE (
      in_id               IN     VARCHAR2,
      in_cd               IN     VARCHAR2,
      person_detls        OUT r_cursor,
      )
IS
begin
  v_start_time := DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME;

open person_detls for

 **some complex select query here**
;

 v_end_time := DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME;
 v_time_taken := v_end_time - v_start_time;

 logging_pkg.write_to_log_table('MY_PROCEDURE',v_time_taken );

END;
```

My Question is:

When is the select query for person_detls actually executed (i.e. the data is actually fetched from tables ) if it is being called from JAVA :

1. When the procedure is executed using
   `CallableStatement.execute();`
2. When resultset is being fetched from CallableStatement with `rs =
   (OracleResultSet) cst.getObject();`
3. When the resultset is actually being accessed by `rs.next()`

I doubt the case is the first one, because, the time logged in my database logging table is very less.

Comment: Usually executed upon the very first fetch from the cursor. In your case, it may be 2 or 3 (I'm not a Java-ist); most probably not the 1. And even that depends on what you mean by "execute a query", because in Oracle executing a query means only creating/reloading an execution plan and allocating some memory for the cursor structure. You'll get the actual performance of the query by fetching _all_ rows from the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the process :

1. SQL statement is `PARSED`. It check the syntax, semantic and whether the query already exists in shared pool.
2. If, the query already exists in shared pool, it goes for soft parse, else hard parse.
3. Then comes the `OPTIMIZATION` stage. Her ethe execution plan is generated.
4. Then comes `ROW SOURCE` generation. this is where the query plan is generated.
5. Finally, the query is `EXECUTED`.

And, to answer your question precisely, all SQLs are parsed, stored, and executed as cursors. So, the query you use in `OPEN-FOR` statement, goes through the above stages and the execution happens at last.

You asked :

> My Question is when is the select query for person_detls actually
>   executed (i.e. the data is actually fetched from tables ) if it is
>   being called from JAVA

PL/SQL is a procedural language, so, when the procedure is called, the marker to execute each line goes from one line to another. Thus, when the query mentioned in the OPEN-FOR statement goes through the above mentioned steps, it is then when it is finally executed.

Comment: My Question is, When is the query actually executed(step 5 of your answer) , from the Java Perspective. Do that happen when I am doing (OracleResultSet) cst.getObject() or when I am doing rs.next(). By execution I here mean scanning the table(s) for respective rows, and picking up the correct rows from the physical data blocks

Comment: And I gave youthe answer in the end. When the procedure is executed. That's when the query is executed.

Answer (score -1):

> The Answer is (1)

[OPEN](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/open_statement.htm) itself would actually prepare the ResultSet. In Other words, the query execution happens here.

[FETCH](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/fetch_statement.htm#i34221) would retrieve the rows from ResultSet (BULK or One By One, based on the FETCH type)

Your `getObject()` would actually materialize the Oracle's ResultSet into JDBC ResultSet, which happens like general `executeQuery()` which do the same job.

Optimization happens here at the `fetchSize`.. number of rows materialised for every fetch.. lower the `fetchSize` higher is the round trips between the java and sql.

More about [fetchsize from Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/java.817/a83724/resltse5.htm)